# Issue with jQuery height and Google Fonts

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I'm trying to calculate the height of a block that contains some words with the following jQuery code:

```
var blockH = $('#my-element').height();
```

Till here no problem.

The issue occurs when I apply the `font-family` rule from css with a Google Fonts family: the sentence that took up two lines with a web safe font is now taking up just one line with Google Fonts applied, but `blockH` value is still referring to the sentence on two lines as if no `font-family` was applied.

Is there anyone that can help me resolving this problem?

Comment: Can we see this issue somewhere ?

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show your problem ?

Comment: It's possible that the height is being worked out before the font has been rendered (which changes the height...)

Comment: would be good to see your code...why do you need to calculate the height?

Comment: The website is on my local machine. I tried to reproduce the issue on jsfiddle, but this time worked. I really cannot figure out how is possible!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that jQuery script was executing before font was loaded.

I resolved it delaying jQuery script execution using [FontDetect](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/FontDetect).